# In Mysql query, 'GROUP BY' number of answers and where pending=' '

Tags: mysql

I have a database with a questions and answers (user table as well for reference to the query below) table.  I am currently doing the query:

```
SELECT questions.*,COUNT(answers.questionid) as num_answers,users.username 
FROM questions LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.questionid = answers.questionid 
LEFT JOIN users ON questions.userid = users.userid 
WHERE questions.pending=''  
GROUP BY questions.questionid
```

The above query works to get me the question details and I counted the number of answers. but, I want to include answers where answers.pending='' so that when I get the count of answers it only shows answers that have been approved.

What do I need to add to the query to make that work, please?

Comment: Please show sample data, expected result and the result you get.

Comment: If a column is in the SELECT then best practice suggests that it should also be in the GROUP BY (unless aggregated)

Answer (score 0):

As per your question you need answers.pending=''

```
SELECT questions.*,COUNT(answers.questionid) as num_answers,users.username 
FROM questions LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.questionid = answers.questionid 
LEFT JOIN users ON questions.userid = users.userid 
WHERE questions.pending='' and  answers.pending=''
GROUP BY questions.questionid
```

use above query

Comment: I've tried that previously but it doesn't return any result for answers that have a pending answer.  i.e.  It will return question 1 (2 answers), question 2 (0 answers) but it won't return any details at all for question 3 which has 2 pending answers.   What I want is to get Question 3 (0 answers) as there are zero approved answers - if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this Code,I think you shoud use null instead of '',

```
SELECT questions.*,COUNT(answers.questionid) as num_answers,users.username 
FROM questions LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.questionid = answers.questionid 
LEFT JOIN users ON questions.userid = users.userid 
WHERE questions.pending IS NULL and  answers.pending IS NULL
GROUP BY questions.questionid
```